# What is a phrase or a different way of saying 'ever since I was a kid'?

Tags: vocabulary, language-formation

'Ever since I was a kid' is very common. I wanted to use something different for my essay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about, "Since childhood" or "Since my youth" or "from an early age"?

Answer (score 1):

These are some basic options you can use:

> *Ever since I was* ____  / *When I was* ____ / *A long time ago, when I was still* ___
>
> > Young
> >     A child
> >     A kid
>
> *In the days of my* ____ / *Back in my* ____ / *In my* ____
>
> > Youth
> >     Childhood

You could use the first set of examples when describing a situation that happened in the past and continues to happen now, such as holding a belief, or a reoccurring event that is still happening, like your favorite restaurant being owned by the same family as before, for example.

The second set of examples are useful when describing either something that occurred in the past but no longer happens now, or an item that used to be available, but is not available anymore.